# Adding an ArrayList Filled With Objects to a Combobox Then Retrieving the Object Back

Tags: java, combobox

I want to first display the objects which are stored in an arraylist onto a combobox. The objects are of type "Items"

Then another method of mine will need to call combobox.getSelectedItem() method to retrieve the object back  the object again is of type "Items";

How can i do this? Here's what ive tried. Tried casting not working.

Method - getItems() just returns an arraylist.

```
for(int i = 0; i < ah.getItems().size(); i++)
{
 itemCombobox.addItem(ah.getItems().get(i).toString());
}

public someMethod()
{
 ah.joinItem((ItemInt) itemComboBox.getSelectedItem());
}
```

The arraylist of items going into the combobox is of type "Items". But the method .joinItem() requires it to be of type ItemInt (interface) but it's not casting it.

Comment: you're adding objects of type `String` to the combobox, not of type `Item`. that being said, you should be doing `ah.getItems().get(i)`, and the renderer will implicitly use `toString` for display.

Comment: Yep i noticed that error and have corrected it. Yet still having the same problem with retrieving a selected item in terms of returning the specific object of type "Item".